# How to redirect to a specific method Yii2 (Advanced Template) ?

Tags: php, yii2

How to navigate to `index` method without automatic login in `frontend contoller` ?

Comment: I cannot understand your question, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extends behaviors method in SiteController:

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],

    ];
}
```

So index action will be available to everyone, instead other pages will require authentication